# Column as variable IN DATA STEP

Tags: sas

i have a problem with choosing a column in depend on variable.
For example, I have columns A1, A2, A3,....,A48 and I have index i. I'd like to choose A1 if i=1, A2 if i=2,...,A48 if i=48.
If has to work in DATA STEP. Has anyone an idea how I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what the `ARRAY` concept is for in SAS.
Let's assume you have dataset with the 49 variables A1-A48 and I and you want to create NEWVAR such that when I=1 then NEWVAR=A1, etc.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  array a a1-a48 ;
  newvar=a(i);
run;
```